# Upload de fotos IOS Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Tenho um aplicativo onde preciso fazer o upload de algumas fotos para um servidor, quando eu faço o upload de uma única foto funciona tudo certo, agora se for de duas ou mais fotos demora um tempo expressivo para finalizar a operação. Eu passo essas fotos transformando elas em base64. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu posso fazer esses uploads mais rápidos.

Comment: Ta usando Swift ou objc? recomendo usar o Alamofire: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire
 Olhe a parte de Uploading, com certeza vai te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você **não precisa** (e **nem deve**), converter as imagens em Base64 para enviar imagens para um servidor remoto.

**Não deve**, porque o Base64 não é um algoritmo de compressão, ele faz o contrário, ele aumenta (e bastante) o peso do payload, talvez seja por isso que seu upload demore tanto. Fazer transferência em Base64 quando as duas pontas conseguem interpretar o mesmo formato binário em comum, é uma péssima prática.

E **não precisa** porque, qualquer servidor com qualquer serviço de aplicação rodando que se preze, consegue ler o campo de boundary binário para converte-lo no formato binário de imagem (gif, jpg, png, wherever) no próprio server.

Se você vai fazer o upload de muitas imagens em alta qualidade, ai já é uma **OUTRA** história. Você vai ter que criar sua própria estratégia de upload para não onerar networking e tempo de interface demais até o upload completar. Nesse caso, eu salvaria tudo local e faria o upload em background aos poucos usando uma task em background ou uma operação secundária com o app aberto.